# eunit Test suite was cancelled error

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, rebar, eunit

I have been trying to use IntellijIdea for erlang development. I created a project from existing sours using rebar. But when I try to run test cases I get following error. This is what I see on console

```
/usr/lib/erlang/bin/erl -pa /tmp/eunit_teamcity9.tmp -pa /mnt/36024D48024D0E75/Users/Buddhika/Documents/Programming/2015/Apache/CouchDB/couch-mrview -eval "eunit:test([couch_mrview_all_docs_tests], [{report, {eunit_teamcity,[]}}, {no_tty, true}])." -s init stop -noshell
Testing started at 4:57 PM ...
Test suite was cancelled. Reason: {abort,
                               {module_not_found,
                                couch_mrview_all_docs_tests}}
```

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Judging from the error message, module `couch_mrview_all_docs_tests` is in a directory that's not in your load path. Perhaps you should try searching under your CouchDB directory for file `couch_mrview_all_docs_tests.beam` and assuming you find it, make sure the directory it's in is supplied with a `-pa` option to your `erl` command.

Comment: Thank you. Path for the .beam files was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Erlang [module is not loaded](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/eunit/src/eunit_test.erl#L277). Use the `-pa` [option](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) to fix this.